# ejabber MUC not notifying on new messages

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I have setup ejabber on a centos 5 system and it works pretty good. The only problem is with MUC. When new messages are received on a MUC, the client doesn't get notified. 
I'm using Adium and Pidgin.

The MUC setup looks like this:

```
 {mod_muc,      [
                  %%{host, "conference.@HOST@"},
                  {access, muc},
                  {access_create, muc_admin},
                  {access_persistent, muc},
                  {access_admin, muc_admin},
                  {default_room_options,
                        [
                          {allow_change_subj, true},
                          {allow_private_messages, true},
                          {allow_user_invites, true},
                          {anonymous, true},
                          {logging, true},
                          {members_by_default, true},
                          {persistent, true},
                          {public, true},
                          {public_list, false}
                        ]}
                 ]},
```

If messages are received between users on regular users' nodes, the notification works well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding this is a client side configuration / usage problem. This is not related to ejabberd.
Please configure or change your client to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

As Mickael pointed out, it is a client side. XMPP by design disables notification on group chats to avoid overflowing your screen with hundreds of notifications.

In the client there's an option to enable notification for group chats. In Adium, the following event needs to be enabled: Message Received (Background Group Chat)